# Is the order of the output of forkjoin always the same as the order of the argument?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hi I was curious about forkjoin while learning Angular.

I heard that forkjoin has two parameters.

Arguments And resultSelector

I have written the following example for this.

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    [ObservableFunctionOne(),
    ObservableFunctionTwo()],
    function(x,y){}).subscribe((results) => {})
```

I know that x and y are the result of ObervableFunction, and Results is an array of the result.

What I want to know here is that the order of x and y and the order of results always follow the calling order of ObservableFunction.

That is, I want to know if x == results [0] == ObservableFunctionOne () and y = results [1] == ObservableFunctionTwo () are always satisfied.

And if the hypothesis is correct, I want to know what happens if one ObservableFunction slows down the response.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the order is the same

Comment: ou.... thank you. but if one observable function is block(ex: http get failed), 
Is the whole waiting?

Comment: That's right. If one of the inner Observables does not emit, the resulting forkJoin will never emit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I heard that forkjoin has two parameters.
>   Arguments And resultSelector

Note that with rxjs 6, the resultSelector argument has been removed and is thus deprecated in previous versions.

> What I want to know here is that the order of x and y and the order of results always follow the calling order of ObservableFunction.

Yes, `forkJoin` will order the emitted values in the same way the observables were ordered when called. This is guaranteed.

> I want to know what happens if one ObservableFunction slows down the response.

`forkJoin` only emits once all observables have completed(!) and emitted at least once(!). For HTTP requests, completing usually happens at the same time as emitting, nonetheless that means all input observables have to emit.

If one of the observables errors, it doesn't complete, and thus the resulting observable will never emit. If you want to handle this case, you can catch the errors:

```
forkJoin([
  this.http.callA().pipe(catchError(() => of(null))),
  this.http.callB().pipe(catchError(() => of(null)))
]).subscribe(([resultA, resultB]) => {
  // if either request failed, resultA / resultB will now just be null
});
```